# What is an appropriate female version of "his man" or "his men" for a subordinate?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, meaning-in-context, ambiguity, gender-positive

When referring to the staff or soldiers of a leader I am finding myself using "his man" and "his men" when not addressing by name. But there are also females in this group and there are times when I want to specify that the person in question is female. Logically I thought of simply using "his woman" or "his women", but this I feel refers more to a partner rather than a subordinate does it not? And using "his staff member/soldier" doesn't tell you what gender this person is.

**Example 1:**

- He gave his man a nod, letting him know to go ahead with the job.

This reads to me as a man in a position of power/leadership is instructing a subordinate to do something.

**Example 2:**

- He gave his woman a nod, letting her know to go ahead with the job.

This reads to me as an authoritative husband/boyfriend instructing a female wife/girlfriend to do something, or am I wrong here?

Comment: Why not just say 'his assistant'? Gender is irrelevant.

Comment: "Man" and "woman" have very different connotations, as you've stated in your question post. The connotation you are looking for does not exist for "women" because they have traditionally not served in the military, which is where "give orders to your men" originates. I would not use this meaning outside of military uses, though.

Comment: If you talk about a female leader you get exactly the same ambiguity with 'her man'. It's the mixed genders that cause the difficulty.

Comment: If you're desperate to express the gender of the underling, "He gave his subordinate a nod, letting her know to go ahead with the job." does the job.

Comment: In another epoch, you could have said "his maid". Rarely used now.